# Nginx Multiple Domains Same IP Not Working

Tags: nginx, server, ip, multiple-domains

I am having issues with Nginx not working with multiple domains pointing to the same IP address. When accessing either domain, they both default to "catacombsfellowship.org.cnf". When accessing edmunddesoto.com, it acts as if it is catacombsfellowship.org and I get an SSL cert error where the cert is for catacombsfellowship.org.

When I run either domain by themselves, they work fine. However, they don't work seamlessly together. What am I doing wrong?

Examples:

File: edmunddesoto.com.cnf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name edmunddesoto.com default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name edmunddesoto.com default_server;
        root /var/www/html/edmunddesoto.com/live;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/edmunddesoto.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/edmunddesoto.com.key;

        location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                        deny all;
        }
}
```

File: catacombsfellowship.org.cnf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name catacombsfellowship.org default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name catacombsfellowship.org default_server;
        root /var/www/html/catacombsfellowship.org/live;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/catacombsfellowship.org.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/catacombsfellowship.org.key;

        location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                        deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Check your configuration using `nginx -t`. You have duplicate servers with the same domain name called `default_server`. If you want to make one of them the default server, you should use the `default_server` keyword on the `listen` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. The issue was somehow it was redirecting to the www.* domains and those were not set in the server_name directive. So, by adding the www.* to the server_name directive, it fixed it.